# Resolving Jar hell

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a custom plugin for Elasticsearch 6.x which has a dependency on httpclient and httpcore jar files. I see that these jars are part of Elasticsearch installation and hence want to use them instead of packaging these jars in my custom plugin.
So, I updated ES_CLASSPATH variable in $ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch-env as follows:
`ES_CLASSPATH="$ES_HOME/lib/*:$ES_HOME/modules/reindex/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:$ES_HOME/modules/reindex/httpcore-4.4.5.jar"`

With above configuration I trying to start Elasticsearch server but I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell! duplicate codebases between plugin and core: [file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/reindex/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/reindex/httpcore-4.4.5.jar]
at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.checkBundleJarHell(PluginsService.java:517) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]  
... 14 more
```

If I remove including these jars in ES_CLASSPATH variable and try to start Elasticsearch server, I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:810) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
... 15 more
```

So how can I add httpclient and httpcore jars to my plugin classpath?
Thanks in advance.

*P.S. I have posted this question couple of days back in ES forum but haven't got any reply. Hence posting it here.*